# c++ using iteration function for compiler

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-construction, iterator, lexical-analysis

So I was trying to build a small lexical scanner that tokenize the text and determine the type of each token. The output should be a text file that  has the line number of a token & token, type at each line. If token is not accepted by any RE then it should report a meaningful error showing the line number of the token, the token, and the error. I used the regexp library in C++, and I now I'm trying to imply the iterator function on the code below but I didn't know how to use it here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("mytext1.txt");
    myfile << " int 33.2 + bla 059 3 " << endl;
    myfile << " void nn + fbla 09 3 " << endl;
    myfile << " int float + bsla 09 3.2 " << endl;
    myfile.close();

    string s;
    regex keywords("int|if|else|while|float|return|void|breack|for");
    regex id("[[:alpha:]]+[[:d:]]*[[:alpha:]]*", regex_constants::icase);
    regex  integer("[[:d:]]+");
    regex  floatt("[[:d:]]+[.]+[[:d:]]+");
    regex symbolls("[&&]|[||]|[<=]|[>=]|[==]|[<]|[>]|[!=]|[=]|[(]|[)]|[{]|[}]|[;]|[,]|[.]|[+]|[-]|[*]|[/]|[/*]|[*/]");
    regex comment("//[[:w:]]*");
    ifstream myfile2("mytext1.txt");

    //int linenum= 1;
    if (myfile2.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myfile2, s, ' '))
        {
            cout << s << ",";
            //cout <<linenum<< s << ",";

            bool match = regex_match(s, floatt);
            if (match) cout << "float number" << endl;
            match = regex_match(s, integer);
            if (match)cout << "integer number" << endl;
            match = regex_match(s, keywords);
            if (match){ cout << "keywords" << endl; goto a;
        }
            match = regex_match(s, id);
            if (match)cout << "identifer" << endl;
        a:  match = regex_match(s, comment);
            if (match)cout << "comment" << endl;
            match = regex_match(s, symbolls);
            if (match)cout << "symbolls" << endl;}

    } myfile2.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *symbols* regex does not do what you think it does.

> Problems:
>   - *Metachars as literals need to be escaped.*
>   - Character classes without quantifiers only match a single character.
>   - Alternations are prioritized left to right (e.g. `a|aw` will match only match `a`we).
>   The fix is to put the longest one first `aw|a`.

Usefull tip: Avoid using posix if you don't have to.

As far as the function `regex_match()`, in C++ this usually requires the regex to match the full line.
To find substrings, use `regex_search()`.

Generally, it's fairly complex to write a parser as each character must be sequentially parsed. At any stage, each token should put the logic in a state that should only accept certain characters or other tokens.

Anyway, good luck.
Below is some doctored up regex from your original's.

```
  keywords  "int|if|else|while|float|return|void|breack|for"
  -----------
       int
    |  if
    |  else
    |  while
    |  float
    |  return
    |  void
    |  breack
    |  for

  id  "[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*"
  -----------
   [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]* [a-zA-Z]* 

  integer  "[0-9]+"
  -----------
   [0-9]+ 

  floatt  "[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+"
  -----------
   [0-9]+ [.]+ [0-9]+ 

  symbols  "[&]{2}|[|]{2}|<=|>=|[=]{2}|!=|/\\*|\\*/|[<>(){};,.+*/=-]"
  -----------
       [&]{2} 
    |  [|]{2} 
    |  <= 
    |  >= 
    |  [=]{2} 
    |  != 
    |  /\* 
    |  \*/ 
    |  [<>(){};,.+*/=-] 


  comment
  -----------
    // [a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```